# .net core 3.1 cookie authentication asking for login when leaving and coming back

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

When I leave my .net core application to go to another page, upon return it asks me to login again.  I have already logged in before navigating away.  I'd think it would hold the cookie longer.  Here is all my authentication code.

Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options => {
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
            options.Cookie.Name = "xxx.Cookies";
        });

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options => {
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Strict;
            options.HttpOnly = HttpOnlyPolicy.None;
            options.Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
        });

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => options.LoginPath = "/LogIn");

services.AddMvc(options => options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter()));
```

Login

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        bool isUservalid = false;
        User user = db.Users.Where(usr => usr.Email == model.Email).FirstOrDefault();

        var isPassword = _passwordManager.Verify(user.Password, model.Password);

        if (isPassword == PasswordVerificationResult.Success)
        {
            isUservalid = true;
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid && isUservalid)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>();

            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email));
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()));

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

            var props = new AuthenticationProperties();
            props.IsPersistent = model.RememberMe;

            HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal, props).Wait();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
        }
        else
        {
            ViewData["message"] = "Invalid UserName or Password!";
        }

        return View();
    }
```

I know the login is working because it lets me get to [Authorize] controllers.

Comment: Just set ExpireTimeSpan to a reasonable timespan and also SlidingExpiration = true

Comment: Also are you using Identity framework or not?

Comment: Could you show your startup `Configure` method to check  middlewares' order?

Comment: I've added the expire time span and sliding expiration and it seems to work now.  I am not using identity framework.  I do use it for password hashing and validation though.